# Restful Webservice in codeigniter with API key

Tags: php, ajax, web-services, rest, codeigniter

I am doing my project in codeigniter 3+ and I have a table to store api key which I generate from dashboard. Then user places the html code from his dashboard on my site (example.com)

```
<div name="api name" data="Api key" sitekey="saltkey"></div>
```

in his website (abc.com) and I render view on his website depending on that key. I use ajax for that as

```
  var a = $('#api-data-reserve').attr('name');
  var b = $('#api-data-reserve').attr('data');
  var c = $('#api-data-reserve').attr('sitekey');
  var webURL = window.location.origin;

  var objects = {'apiName': a,'api': b, 'sitekey':c, 'url': webURL};
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
     url: base_url + 'application/viewSender',
      cache   : true,
    data: {"inputs" : JSON.stringify(objects)},
    //async: true,

    success: function(msg)
    {
       clearconsole(); 
        $("#api-data-reserve").html(msg);
        $('#api-data-reserve').removeAttr('name');
        $('#api-data-reserve').removeAttr('data');
        $('#api-data-reserve').removeAttr('sitekey');
        $('#api-data-reserve').removeAttr('id');
    }
});
```

And in controller I check for the api key if it exists in database or not and if exists I render the view on clients website.

Now My question is threefold:

1. is it secure that I'm doing to render view? If not How should I do it?
2. How can I use that valid (key that exists in database) API key provided to user for restful webservice's API key for database query or restful services as in https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver without updating key and auto generating them on fly?
3. How can I make all this secure? Should I go with HTTPS too?